# How to Parse through hundreds of files and move them to their respected file via powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that will move hundreds of account PDFs into their respective folders. I am very new to powershell and my basic script for now I was able to move one file to the other folder and match its name and date format of 052020 using this script:

```
cd \\Sageshare\share

copy-item -path "\\Sageshare\share\Reconciliation\PDF Recon Center\DEA RECON 05292020.pdf" -destination "\\Sageshare\share\Reconciliation\Account Rec. Sheets\Separate Accounts\DEA" | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*DEA RECON 052020*'}
```

Since that is only one file going into its named folder in another directory, how would I do this with 400 files going each into a respective folder? If I can get this then I am going to run into the issue to where the 05 date is going to need to change to 06 and so on until the end of the year where it will also have to change the month and year. But I would really like to just figure out the first part for now.

Comment: You dont work in Powershell like this. Can you please give me a little more information about how is the connection from the file --> respective target folder?

Comment: The files and folders are located in a network drive, from my example it shows copying the DEA RECON 05292020.pdf file from Reconciliation\PDF Recon Center to Reconciliation\Account Rec. Sheets\Separate Accounts\DEA and then I piped where the file name is like DEA RECON 052020.  Is there not a way to do this with multiple files sending them all to different folders?

Answer (score 1):

I have make you an code example which shows you how to work in Powershell. You cant break anything when you run my code until you uncomment the two lines at the end

```
$sourceFolder = '\\Sageshare\share\Reconciliation\PDF Recon Center'
$targetFolder = '\\Sageshare\share\Reconciliation\Account Rec. Sheets\Separate Accounts\DEA'
$files = Get-ChildItem $sourcefolder -Filter *.pdf

$files | ForEach-Object {

    echo ('Processing file ' + $_.Name)
    $regex = [regex]::Match($_.Name, '\s([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})[.]pdf')
    echo ('Month ' + $regex.Groups[1].Value)
    echo ('Date ' + $regex.Groups[2].Value)
    echo ('Year ' + $regex.Groups[3].Value)

    $targetFolderTmp = (Join-Path $targetFolder -childpath ($regex.Groups[3].Value + '\' + $regex.Groups[1].Value + '\' + $regex.Groups[2].Value))

    Write-Host ('Copy to: ' + $targetFolderTmp)

    #if(-not $targetFolderTmp) {mkdir $targetFolderTmp} uncomment if code is good
    #copy-item -path $_.FullName -destination targetFolderTmp uncomment if code is good


}
```